# Find the general solutions of the system.

Tags: matrices, systems-of-equations

I'm having trouble understanding how to approach the problem, I am given:

$x' = \begin{bmatrix}-9&0&1\\0&-7&-4\\0&1&-11\end{bmatrix}x$

I have found that λ = -9 with a multiplicity of 3, and use the value to convert the matrix into:

\begin{bmatrix}0&0&1\\0&2&-4\\0&1&-2\end{bmatrix}

I just have no idea where to go from here.

Comment: the minimum polynomial and the characteristic polynomial, there is a single Jordan block.

Comment: Can't tell if you have ever heard of Jordan form. Call your matrix $A$  and the "converted"  matrix $A+9I.$   Since $(A+9I)^3 = 0$  but $(A+9I)^2 \neq 0,$  take a column vector $w$   such that $(A+9I)^2 w\neq 0.$   Then calculate $ v = (A+9I)w.$  Finally $u = (A+9I) v.$   Make $P$  be the matrix with columns $u,v,w.$    Finally $J = P^{-1} A P$

Answer (score 1):

First, you have to find the eigenvector corresponding to the eigenvalue (λ = -9).

You have to find the 3 x 1 matrix that when multiplied by \begin{bmatrix}0&0&0\\0&2&1\\1&-4&-2\end{bmatrix} results in the zero vector.

Doing the math, we find \begin{bmatrix}1&0&0\\\end{bmatrix} We can see that there is only one linearly independent eigenvector corresponding to the eigenvalue when the eigenvalue is of multiplicity 3. This means the eigenvector is degenerate as opposed to complete.

Look up generalized eigenvectors and you can find the complete answer to your question.